# PHP ajax post data empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting form data from create.`php` as below using `$.ajax`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var request;
    $("#create-pto").submit(function(e) {
        // Abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        request = $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data:  serializedData
        }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

I can see the posted data and i can log post success.

But in index.php could not retrieve posted data.

This is what i am trying in index.php

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Form :

```
       <form class="form-horizontal"  id="create-pto"  >
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-   label">App ID</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="app-id" id="app-id" placeholder="App ID">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">App Name</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="app-name" id="app-name"
                               placeholder="App Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Instance Name</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="ins-name"
                               placeholder="Instance Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="create" class="btn btn-success">Create PTO</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Pls help.

Comment: your form code please?

Comment: When you watch your "network" with the web tool brower, is it ok?

Comment: #create-pto is form id or button id ?

Comment: #create-pto is form id

Comment: When form will submit ,without any submit button ? Can you post your form code

Comment: @davidJawphan why do you think there is no submit button?

Comment: So I ask you to post your form code

Comment: posted @davidJawphan but as i say i can see data from form getting posted successfully ! i just cant retrieve it in index.php

Comment: my code is not working for you??

Comment: @VijaysinhParmar no! sorry!

Comment: I tested in my system I am getting data in index.php file.

Comment: what do you use in index.php to get data ? pls

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the contentType on your JavaScript code:

`contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

And if you want to keep the contentType to `json`, try this way on your PHP file:

`echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: You should use JSON.stringify(serializedData) to send json type data. and try to catch them using $_REQUEST.

Comment: Did u try with var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: I tried contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , data:serializedData and var_dump($_REQUEST) I get array(0) { }  in index.php for var_dump($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.serialize()` you need to change `contentType` to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

If you want to keep `contentType: 'application/json'` you have to use JSON.stringify instead.

Also note that JSON strings in POST requests are retreived using `file_get_contents('php://input');` not `$_POST`

Comment: i changed contentType: to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. and tried file_get_contents('php://input'); but echoing doesnt print anything on index.php

Comment: @Spdexter Try not serializing or stringifying the data at all and check if `$_POST` gets populated

Answer (score 1):

Change your

> contentType : 'application/json'

to

> dataType: "JSON"

It will start work.. I tested code on my system.

Answer (score 0):

try `type:GET` instead of `type:POST`,also call *var_dump($_GET)* in `index.php`